# SoftLayer order from quote fails with error Price ID 876 does not exist

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We are trying to order a BareMetal server in the Sydney1 DC via the API from an existing quote created in the portal.
We are extracting our quote container using this method in python:

```
    container = client['Billing_Order_Quote'].getRecalculatedOrderContainer(id=quote_id)
```

We are not making any changes to the Price IDs in the container.  When we try to verify the order or place the order using:

```
    result = client['Product_Order'].verifyOrder(container)
```

It fails with the following error:

```
    Failed to order due to error: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): Price # 876 does not exist.
```

This is the JSON extract of the container showing ID 876:

```
 "currentPriceFlag": "",
  "hourlyRecurringFee": "0",
  "id": 876,
  "item": {
    "activePresaleEvents": [],
    "attributes": [],
    "availabilityAttributes": [],
    "bundle": [],
    "description": "Non-RAID",
    "id": 487,
    "itemCategory": {
      "categoryCode": "disk_controller",
      "id": 11,
      "name": "Disk Controller",
      "quantityLimit": 0,
      "questions": []
    },
    "itemTaxCategoryId": 166,
    "keyName": "DISK_CONTROLLER_NONRAID",
    "softwareDescriptionId": "",
    "thirdPartyPolicyAssignments": [],
    "upgradeItemId": ""
  },
```

Have tried using different quotes with different hardware.  If we order via the portal using the same quote it works so just the API is having some problem with `Non-Raid`?  Also this same script worked a week ago so have there been any changes made to the Product_Order API?  The quote is also a new quote created on the same day as when we started receiving the error.

Answer (score 1):

what I know the control portal uses these methods for quotes:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Quote/verifyOrder
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Quote/placeOrder

So try to modify your code using those methods instead e.g.

```
result = client['Billing_Order_Quote'].verifyOrder(container,id=quoteId)
```

Note:replace quoteId with the Id of the quote

and let me know if the issue is still reproducible.

well I was to able to reproduce the issue and I have a question. How did you create the quote? did you use the same account to create the quote? because something is wrong with the quote for some reason it is using an invalid price for your account. Please check that the 
price 876 is listed when you call the following method:

```
result = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package'].getItemPrices(id=packageID)
Note: replace the packageID with the package that your quote is using, it seems is 253
```

If you cannot see the price 876 listed, that is the issue and it is related with the wrong creation of the quote.

You can change that price for a valid one in order to head off the error e.g.

```
"""
Order from account's quote.
This script creates an order from a account's quote presented
in the SoftLayer Customer Portal's (https://control.softlayer.com/account/quotes)

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getQuotes
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Quote/getRecalculatedOrderContainer
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Quote/placeOrder
@License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
@Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
# So we can talk to the SoftLayer API:
import SoftLayer

# For nice debug output:
import pprint
"""
Your SoftLayer API username and key.
Generate an API key at the SoftLayer Customer Portal
"""
API_USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=API_USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

"""
Set the id of the quote from which you want to create the order,
use SoftLayer_Account::getQuotes method to get a list of quotes from account
"""
quoteId = 2135231
# Get the order data by using SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Quote::getRecalculatedOrderContainer method
orderTemplates = client['SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Quote'].getRecalculatedOrderContainer(id=quoteId)
# Changing the wrong price for a valid one
prices = []
for price in orderTemplates["prices"]:
    if price["id"] != 876:
        prices.append(price)

prices.append({"id": 141949})
orderTemplates["prices"] = prices

try:
    """
    Verify the order container is right. If this returns an error
    then fix your order container and re-submit. Once ready then place
    your order with the placeOrder() method.
    """
    receipt = client['SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Quote'].verifyOrder(orderTemplates, id=quoteId)
    pprint.pprint(receipt)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("error faultCode=%s, faultString=%s"
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

Somehow the control portal must be changing the invalid price before performing the order, that's why it is working in the portal, because as I told you before both are using the same API method to order.

Regards

Comment: Tried both verifyOrder and placeOrder and both fail with following error:  `Failed to order due to error: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception): Object does not exist to execute method on. (SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Quote::placeOrder)`

Comment: oh I see what is happening that is my error sorry the methods need an initparameter which is the quoteId I updated the e.g adding that please try again

Comment: Ok that fails with the same error `Price # 876 does not exist`

Comment: can you give me the id of the quote? it seems that is this "2135231" , but I am not quite sure.

Comment: Yes I created the quote using the same account.  However having said that I did noticed a bug with having several accounts linked to an IBMid.  If I was logged into one account then switched to another account and placed a quote the quote came up with the first accounts details?  However I confirmed this quote shows up in the list of quotes for the same account  API credentials I am using in the script.  Also noticed today I cannot switch accounts in the portal using IBMid.  Do you know if there is an issue with IBMid today?

Comment: Nop I do not know about such issue, I recommend you to open an ticket in softlayer asking about that issue likely that is the cause of the issue related to the price.